# json encode in php not working

Tags: php, angularjs, json

Here is my code . I want check validate with angular and php
here is html . I want check validate this form

```
<form ng-submit="dk()">
<label for="">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData.name">

{{errorName}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{{formData}}
{{message}}
```

here is angular . I send http request to php code

```
function dkController($scope,$http){
            $scope.formData ={};
            $scope.dk = function(){
                $http({
                    method:'POST',
                    url:'test.php',
                    data:$.param($scope.formData),

                }).then(onSuccess)

                function onSuccess(response){
                    $scope.mydata = response.data;
                    if($scope.mydata.success==false){
                        $scope.errorName = response.data.errors.name;
                    }else{
                        $scope.message = response.data.message;
                        $scope.errorName='';
                    }
                }
```

here is php . i'm doing check code in here

```
  <?php
    $data=array();
    $errors=array();
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','project'); 
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $username =$_POST['name'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM hoso where username='$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        $errors['username']='You cant use this username';
    }
    }


    if(!empty($errors)){
        $data['success']=false;
        $data['errors']=$errors;
    }else{
        $data['success']=true;
        $data['message']='Success';
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
    ?>
```

here is show `{"success":true,"message":"Success"}`
I dont know why not have errors in this json . Where is my wrong . Please help me . Thank

Comment: Everything looks good to me.  What are you trying to achieve here

Comment: @PhpDev I want do like this https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way . If I check empty username it's work fine , but when I check  in database , it not work

Comment: You sure you have to check for `isset($_POST['name'])` and not for `$_POST['username']`? If `$_POST['name']` isn't set it won't throw any errors.

Comment: @TomUdding yes . I'm using `isset($_POST['name'])`

Comment: I meant; do you use `name` or `username` in your form? (Could you add your form code to the question)

Comment: @TomUdding sr . I check again and add code . Can you help me . It not work . When I submit , it only show Success

Comment: check `if(count($errors)>0){` instead of `if(!empty($errors)){`

Comment: @webDev thank for help , but not work too

Comment: see in your angular onSuccess method you are trying to get undefined value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First In your angular method `onSuccess` only put following, update as follows

```
function onSuccess(response){
    $scope.mydata = response.data;
}
```

and to see what your are getting, please replace `{{message}}` with
`{{mydata}}`
By this you can see whats going on.
Do above just to check what you are getting from your PHP script. The above codes are not solution.
And you have error in your angular method onSuccess too, correct your angular values like instead of `response.data.errors.name;` use  `response.data.errors.username;`

After doing all corrections that I mentioned, please print `{{errorName }}` and see the message.
**OR** Simply use following 
**Updated:**
HTML

```
<form ng-submit="dk()">
<label for="">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData.name">

{{errorName}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{{formData}}
{{errorName}}
```

JS

```
function onSuccess(response){
    $scope.mydata = response.data;
    if($scope.mydata.success==false){
        $scope.errorName = response.data.errors.username;
    }else{
        $scope.message = response.data.message;
        $scope.errorName='Success msg';
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you misunderstand me . I want when write username in input , php will check in database , if have username in database , will show :' You cant use this username' . Thank for help'

Comment: yes so first check what you are getting from your PHP script by modifying onSuccess method and replacing message with mydata on html page. Its just for test not for your problem. I want you to see what your are getting from your php script. I have updated the post.

Comment: i'm getting `{"success":true,"message":"Success"}` here

Comment: you dont have `$scope.errorName = response.data.errors.name;` because you have `$errors['username']='You cant use this username';`. Thats why you have to use `$scope.errorName = response.data.errors.username;` not `$scope.errorName = response.data.errors.name;`. cant you see you are passing message as $error['username'] but accessing using errors.name.

Comment: omg . I'm wrong its . It is `formData.username` instead `formData.name`. You save my day . Thank a lot !!